# ffmpeg image extracted from video, quality issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to extract the jpeg images from the rtsp stream. I observed that generated image quality is not good. bottom portion of the image is always blurred or pixelated.

If i stream same video in VLC player everything works as expected. Has anyone seen this issue before any help is greatly appreciated. 
[Image generated from ffmpeg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT9kK.jpg)

Comment: Could you please provide full command line how do you extract images using ffmpeg?!

Comment: Add `-q:v 1`. You can try higher values till it looks ok.

Comment: Here is the command i am trying                                                         ffmpeg -i "rtsp://172.30.11.213:556/mpeg4" -r 10 -q:v 9  -f image2 C:\kiwi\image%d.jpg  I also tried higher values for -q:v. Value 10 gives comparatively good output but still it is pixelated.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly same issue, blurred, pixelated bottom of image. Apparently problem was missing packet. I solved it thanks to recommendation in this post https://superuser.com/questions/663928/ffmpeg-to-capture-stills-from-h-264-stream  and my commamnd looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -y -i ${rtspUrl} -q:v 1 -vframes 1 snapshot${i}.jpg
```

Comment: No need for `-q:v` when outputting PNG.

Comment: Thanks @llogan I corrected my answer, with jpg output.